# How to I move a directory in python using shutil library?

Tags: python, file-handling, shutil

I'm trying to move a file but it won't work. It keeps giving the error "Errno 2: File or directory does not exist". The code is shown below

```
import shutil

original = '%userprofile%/Desktop/Test'
New = '%userprofile%/Desktop/Test2'

shutil.move(original, New)
```

if anyone has any advice on how to solve this please help me.

Comment: I would have to assume environment variable expansion is not supported by `shutil`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.expandvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) to expand the `%userprofile%` variable and the resultant path can be passed into the `shutil.move` API.

```
>>> help(os.path.expandvars)
Help on function expandvars in module ntpath:

expandvars(path)
    Expand shell variables of the forms $var, ${var} and %var%.

    Unknown variables are left unchanged.
```

ie,

```
shutil.move(os.path.expandvars(original), os.path.expandvars(New))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `%userprofile%` is the only variable you need, it can be done with `pathlib.Path.expanduser` as such:

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

original = Path('~/Desktop/Test').expanduser()
New = Path('~/Desktop/Test2').expanduser()

shutil.move(original, New)
```